# i want to use variable globally in veiws.py

Tags: python, django

veiws.py

```
def getBusRouteId(strSrch):

    end_point = "----API url----"
    parameters = "?ServiceKey=" + "----my servicekey----"
    parameters += "&strSrch=" + strSrch
    url = end_point + parameters
    retData = get_request_url(url)

    asd = xmltodict.parse(retData)
    json_type = json.dumps(asd)
    data = json.loads(json_type)

    if (data == None):
        return None
    else:
        return data

def show_list(request)

    Nm_list=[]
    dictData_1 = getBusRouteId("110")
    for i in range(len(dictData_1['ServiceResult']['msgBody']['itemList'])):
        Nm_list.append(dictData_1['ServiceResult']['msgBody']['itemList'][i]['busRouteNm'])

    return render(request, 'list.html', {'Nm_list': Nm_list})
```

There is a dict data that was given by API
In 'def getBusRouteId', some Xml data is saved by dict data
In 'def show_list', I call 'def getBusRouteId' so 'dictData_1' get a dict data
And I want to refer this dictData_1 in another function
Is there any way to use dictData_1 globally?

Answer (score 2):

Either store those data in a session (if those are short-lived data) or in the database (if you want to persist them).

The point is that a WSGI app is typically deployed as a pool of long-running processes, with a "supervisor" process that will dispatch incoming HTTP requests to the first available process (or to a newly spawned one etc), so using process-wide globals to store per-user data does NOT work as you always end up with user A getting data from user B, or no data at all, etc.

NB: this kind of issues may not appear when testing with a single user on the dev server, but it's still GARANTEED to break in production.

Also, totally unrelated but:

1/ this bit seems totally useless - you serialize a dict to json then unserialize it to a dict, which, unless you have custom serialization / unseralization hooks (which is not the case here), it's functionalmly a no-op.

```
json_type = json.dumps(asd)
data = json.loads(json_type)
```

2/ Here:

```
end_point = "----API url----"
parameters = "?ServiceKey=" + "----my servicekey----"
parameters += "&strSrch=" + strSrch
url = end_point + parameters
retData = get_request_url(url)
```

I don't know how `get_request_url` is implemented but if you are using python-requests, it already knows how to turn a dict into a (properly encoded) querystring. And if you're using the standard urllib packages, they ALSO provide a way to turn a dict into a properly built querystring. This makes for more robust AND more maintainable code.

3/ you may want to learn [how to properly use Python's for loops](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements)

Here:

```
 Nm_list=[]
 dictData_1 = getBusRouteId("110")

 for i in range(len(dictData_1['ServiceResult']['msgBody']['itemList'])):
     Nm_list.append(dictData_1['ServiceResult']['msgBody']['itemList'][i]['busRouteNm'])
```

Python `for` loop naturally iterate over the sequence, yielding an item from the sequence in each iteration. So the proper way to write this is:

```
 Nm_list=[]
 for item in dictData_1['ServiceResult']['msgBody']['itemList']:
     Nm_list.append(item['busRouteNm'])
```

which is both much more readable AND much more efficient.

Also, this can be further improved using list comprehension:

```
# intermediate var for readability
source = dictData_1['ServiceResult']['msgBody']['itemList']
Nm_list = [item['busRouteNm'] for item in source]
```

which is even more efficient (it's optimized by the runtime to avoid memory reallocation when the list grows).

4/ this:

```
if (data == None):
     return None
 else:
     return data
```

is a very convoluted way to write:

```
  return data
```

(also note that since `None` is a singleton, the preferred way is to use the identity test operator `is`, ie `if data is None` - same result but more idiomatic).

Answer (score 0):

I understood that you want to perform some operations on `dict_data` returned by `getBusRouteId()` and pass them to another function.

SOLUTION - Just passing the `dict_data` as an argument to another function will work. No need to make global variables.

Comment: I guess i assumed it to be obvious. If that is the case, then i think it is good to store the data you want to use in your API Session or some shared resource like a file to dump and reuse data. Both depends upon the USECASE.